# Book series about a boy who slips through time while buying milk for his mother, ending up in a variety of time periods

Tags: story-identification, books, time-travel

I read this series book as a kid about 7-8 years ago and I think back then it was very recently published, but I could be wrong. I remember some of the plot line and stories, but I can't remember the name of the book or the character's name for the life of me.

The story starts with this boy and how his mother is asking him to go buy milk to eat with what she was baking, but something happens while he's outside and he slips through time.

In one of the books, he is in the Wild West, in another the future. I remember in the beginning of every book, they made it sound like this was actually real and that it was someone's diary they published.

There is another book I remember where he is taken by a puppeteer master who is using kids to steal for him. Also, he can't ever get back to his house or his timeline.

I think there were at least 4-5 books that were for different timelines. Also at the beginning of each one, there was like something that made it seem like they published a diary; it was like "if you see this" type of thing.

Does anybody know anything what the name of the book/series might be?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this, and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you know roughly how many books there were in the series, and do you recall anything about any of the covers?

Comment: Okay, thanks; I've added those extra details to your question. If you want to make any additions or alterations to the question yourself, you can do so using the [edit] function.

Comment: Also, if anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark their answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].